# How to choose the right predictors for a classfication model?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, r, random-forest, logistic-regression

I am working on a classification problem. I have two models:

1. Logistic regression model
2. Random Forest model

For the first model, if I choose the only predictors with p-values<0.05 I will reduce the accuracy, recall, etc. The IV (and WOE) predictors selection are not the same as the predictors that comply with the p-value rule.

On the other hand, Random Forest does not give p-values, only importance metrics, which are similar the IV predictors.

**So, which methods should use to select the right predictors so I can compare the two models?**

Thanks for reading this and I hope you can help me. I will be glad to give more details.

Comment: What is the goal of your analysis?

Comment: I want to predict clients that they are going to upsell next month.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend finding the best estimators for each model using a validation set and then comparing the final models, each one with different predictors, on the same dataset.